# Algorithm that costs time to run but easy to verify?

Tags: algorithm, time

I am designing an website for experiment, there will be a button which user *must* click and hold for a while, then release, then client submits AJAX event to server.

However, to prevent from autoclick bots and fast spam, I want the hold time to be very real and not skip-able, e.g. doing some calculation. The point is to waste actual CPU time, so that you can't simply guess the AJAX callback value or turning faster system clock to bypass it.

Are there any algorithm that

1. fast & easy to generate a **challenge** on a server
2. costs some time to execute on the client side, no spoof or shortcut the time.
3. easy & fast to verify the **response** result on a server?

Comment: How about brute forcing a simple hash? generate a random value server side, hash it and pass it to the client to brute force.

Comment: Or factorize a large integer, large enough so that the factorization takes time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're looking for a [Proof-of-work system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof-of-work_system).

The most popular algorithm seems to be [Hashcash](http://www.hashcash.org/) (also on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashcash)), which is used for bitcoins, among other things. The basic idea is to ask the client program to find a hash with a certain number of leading zeroes, which is a problem they have to solve with brute force.

Basically, it works like this: the client has some sort of token. For email, this is usually the recipient's email address and today's date. So it could look like this:

```
bob@example.com:04102011
```

The client now has to find a random string to put in front of this:

```
asdlkfjasdlbob@example.com:04202011
```

such that the hash of this has a bunch of leading 0s. (My example won't work because I just made up a number.)

Then, on your side, you just have to take this random input and run a *single* hash on it, to check if it starts with a bunch of 0s. This is a *very* fast operation.

The reason that the *client* has to spend a fair amount of CPU time on finding the right hash is that it is a brute-force problem. The only know want to do it is to choose a random string, test it, and if it doesn't work, choose another one.

Of course, since you're not doing emails, you will probably want to use a different token of some sort rather than an email address and date. However, in your case, this is easy: you can just make up a random string server-side and pass it to the client.

One advantage of this particular algorithm is that it's very easy to adjust the difficulty: just change how many leading zeroes you want. The more zeroes you require, the longer it will take the client; however, verification still takes the same amount of time on your end.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but before sending the challenge to the client, I presume the server already new the correct answer, so after the client finishes the calculation and upload, the server simply match against the correct answer? Is my understanding of the procedure right?

Comment: @est: No. The idea is that verifying a correct hash is easy--does it start with the right number of zeroes? The client has to find some string, using a predifined token (like the email address and date) along with a random number, that produces a hash with the requisite number of zeroes.

Comment: thanks, another question: What are the chances that the clients random puts some leading zeros and some junk string after, and it matches the correct answer?

Comment: @est: The idea is that the client passes you a string containing a given token that, when *hashed*, has a bunch of zeroes. So the chance of getting it right the first time around is something like 1/2^20, which is why this method takes so much brute force.

Comment: ahh I see your edit now, Hashcash is awesome idea. thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Came back to answer my own question. This is called **Verifiable Delay Function**

> The concept was first proposed in 2018 by Boneh et al., who proposed several candidate structures for constructing verifiable delay functions and it is an important tool to add time delay in decentralized applications. To be exact, the verifiable delay function is a function f:X→Y that takes a prescribed wall-clock time to compute, even on a parallel processor, ond outputs a unique result that can effectively output the verification. In short, even if it is evaluated on a large number of parallel processors and still requires evaluation of f in a specified number of sequential steps

https://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/22/19/7524

The idea of VDF is a step forward than @TikhonJelvis's PoW answer because apparently it "takes a prescribed wall-clock time to compute, even on a parallel processor"