# Voting System (Multiple sites), solution for a toplist that has no callback

Tags: php, javascript, session

**Hello everyone**

I have a vote system, and Ill explain how does it work.

There are some websites called *toplists* that contains the top 100 items in it (depending on vote count).

Okay so I've made a `voting system`, that will have 5 different buttons, linking to different toplists.

**Some toplists have callback (A GET callback), and some doesn't.**

I want to ***trick*** the client, so it will make sure he will vote, I know it is impossible to 100% guarantee, but possible to trick the client from cheating.

**My idea:**

When user clicks on one of the links, he will have to wait `8 seconds` before clicking the 'submit' button, to get his voting points.

First result in my head: JavaScript.

And that's how I was planning to do this:
(Just example, it is not the actual code!)

```
#buttonid.click (function() {
var time = **current_time + 8 seconds**
});

#submit.click(function() {
if (current_time < time) {
return error 1
} else {
process...
});
```

This is a little example of how I thought of doing this, so `variable time = this current time` when he clicked on the button, `+ 8 seconds`.

So when he clicks submit, it checks if the `current time` is `less` than variable `time by seconds`.
If yes, then return an `error message`.

**But I am not to sure how to do so. Is that a good way of doing this?**

**basically this is my question:**

How can I trick the client? Any other ways?.

How can I do the JavaScript seconds + time trick?

Comment: if you want to make sure that votes are legit, you should use something like recaptcha instead.

Comment: How would that help? they can just fill the recaptcha and not vote.

Comment: Also the user could just bypass it by using the raw http requests, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16377345/algorithm-that-costs-time-to-run-but-easy-to-verify for a way to ensure the browser waits

Comment: I see. How's the timing helping in your use case? People will not be enticed to vote if they have to wait, and they will just leave the site. Please clarify.

Comment: In that case we don't care, I just need a 10 second timer, it might help a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably just use `setTimeout`:

```
#buttonid.click (function() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        /* enable submit button */
    }, 8000);
});
```

But keep in mind doing anything client-side isn't very secure, this would be trivial to bypass.

Comment: But I don't want to let the client know we're tricking him, I want to send an error message instead.

Can I do preventDefault and fill up .html() of some div as an error?

Comment: Yes I know it is not secure, but I can't see any way to do it PHP sided without reloading the page.